# How to capture only top element event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I would really appreciate if someone can help me here. 
I want to get the reverse effect of stopPropagation, I want that only the div element onClick will be called and the nested onClick to be ignored. is it possible ?

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    const top = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log('top')
    }

    const bottom = (e: any) => {
        // e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('bottom')
    }
    return (
    <div onClickCapture={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => top(e)} className="home-page">
        <button onClick={(e) => bottom(e)}>press me</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: If you want your tle to capture why do you have click on div

Comment: i just want to know if it possible to do thatת even if there's a nested element with event listenerץ i'm not sure why would someone want this but i'm still curious

Comment: So you want to do Event Capturing and stop its propagation with the parent. add `e.stopPropagation` in top(e).